# Perl Scripting: Running mv as external command

Tags: perl, mv

I'm trying to run this command as a part of my perl script:

```
`mv $n1 ../out`
```

where $n1 is a file name i'm getting from a previous subroutine.
I'm getting a error as below:

```
mv: missing destination file operand after `test.pl'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
sh: line 1: ../out: is a directory
```

Can anyone please help. If i run the command individually it runs fine.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to `mv` when [`File::Copy::move`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Copy) exists?

Comment: Are you sure `$n1` is filled? It looks like you are executing `mv ../out` because `$n1` is empty.

Comment: i can assure you that $n1 is filled. i'm also printing it before the the mv command. does $n1 have to be is some special quotes?

Comment: also file::copy::move would transfer the contents... i need the file out of the directory!

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$n1` when you run that command? Does it contain whitespace? Is on a different device?

Comment: $n1 is a filename. <alphanumeric>.xml

Comment: There's no characters like `|` or `&` in it at all? It would be better for all of us if you provide the output of `print "mv $n1 ../out\n"` for a value of `$n1` it fails for.

Comment: @NimitShah: No, what *exactly* is the value of `$n1`?  If you add `print "\$n1 = \"$n1\"\n" to your script, what does it print?  Don't summarize or approximate it, copy-and-paste the exact output.  If you knew which details are unimportant enough not to bother telling us, you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Konerak & flesk: thank you all the problem is solved. i was the culprit. i did not chomp the file properly. by mistake i commented that line. Apologies for troubling you and thank you very much for the help. much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script that reproduces something very similar to the error messages you're seeing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $n1 = "test.pl\n";

`mv $n1 ../out`;
```

The problem is that `$n` ends with a newline (maybe you read it from a file and didn't `chomp` it?), so the command executed by the shell is:

```
mv test.pl
../out
```

If this is indeed the problem, you could have tracked it down by printing the value of `$n1`:

```
print "DEBUG: \$n1 = \"$n1\"\n";
```

Note that the

```
`...`
```

syntax is intended to capture the output of a shell command.  Since you're just renaming a file, it would make more sense to use `system`:

```
system 'mv', $n1, '../out';
```

or, as Quentin suggested in a comment, to use `File::Copy::move`, or the built-in `rename` function if you're sure you're not moving the file across filesystem boundaries.

Comment: the file is chomped for sure....
print "Enter the name of your file:";
chomp($file_name = <STDIN>);

Comment: when i used your system command i got this error:
mv: cannot stat `': No such file or directory

Comment: @NimitShah: Then you don't have a file whose name is the string contained in `$n1`.

Comment: @NimitShah: Did you read the entire answer? You could at least tell us the exact output of `print "DEBUG: \$n1 = \"$n1\"\n";` if you expect any further help.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Konerak & flesk: thank you all the problem is solved. i was the culprit. i did not chomp the file properly. by mistake i commented that line. Apologies for troubling you and thank you very much for the help. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What Konerak said above.

You should probably perform a check before calling the command, also if you don't need to save the output of the command use system() rather than back ticks, it makes the code far more legible.

```
if ($n1 ) {
    system("mv $n1 ../out");
}
else{
   die "No value assigned to \$n1 from previous routine routine_name()\n";
}
```

**EDIT**
You could change the check to ensure that the result you are trying to move exists and is a normal file: ie

```
if ( -f $n1 ){
....
```

Comment: tried with the above code, got the same result. Just to let u know m running this code on CYGWIN.

Comment: $n1 would be like test.sh. It has been chomped.

Comment: you get 
    mv: missing destination file operand after `test.pl'
For the command above? what happens if you do the following?
    if ($n1 ) {
        print "command is: {mv $n1 ../out}\n";
        system("mv $n1 ../out");
    }
    else{
       die "No value assigned to \$n1 from previous routine routine_name()\n";
    }

Ugh, how do I format comments

Comment: @SkryneSaver: got it! there was this particular line which was creating problems... it has worked well with back ticks...